# ReactJS - Lifting State Up in a state heavy system

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frameworks

I'm working on an online instruction set simulator and assembler. I'm building it in React because it's very state-heavy, but I'm wondering how I can possibly keep lifting the state up on a state-heavy project like this. Currently my project is divided into many different components, but another programmer recently pointed out that I'm handling my information improperly.

Most of my data is tab-dependent. So, when clicking on a tab, an event is sent to the app.  This will effect every single component (aside from the navbar and global settings). This updates almost the entire app. But if I'm updating a simple text field, I'd also have to send the data up to the root app class. This puts most of the code within the root class, and causes a lot of spaghetti code. How can I possibly:

A) Prevent re-rendering the entire app every time I change a single text field

B) Complicating my code to the point where every onChange and every state is maintained within the root node

For reference, I'm revamping this project of mine: https://donn.github.io/Oak.js/

Comment: Do you use redux. You use case seems a likely candidate for redux.
Also look into Reacts context api

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Redux isn't so much necessary now that we have the context api? But I am using the latter a bit. But there's still the issue of shoving every single bit of data into a single context.

Comment: Depends. wi ould go with redux and split the data into multiple reducers (if they are not related) and then use them on the components as needed

Comment: redux's react connector *uses* context. context does not replace redux. context is "react" context. redux is a global store that sits outside of react that can be put onto context. redux is certainly a fine choice for you, but what you want can also be achieved by having state live in separate context containers. the downside to that is when you need to access state from one context in another, something that redux handles gracefully via middleware